# Extracting Wikimedia pageview statistics

Tags: download, pageviews, wikimedia-dumps

Wikipedia provides all their page views in a hourly text file. (See for instance http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/2014/2014-01/)

For a project is need to extract keywords and their associated page views for the year 2014. But seeing that one file (representing 1 hour, consequently totalling 24*365 files) is ~80MB. This can be a hard task doing manual.

My questions:
1. Is there any way to download the files automatically? (the files are structured properly this could be helpful)

Answer (score 1):

Download? Sure, that's easy:

```
wget -r -np http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/
```

Recursive wget does it. Note, these files are deprecated now; you probably want to use http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-all-sites/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this project: https://github.com/idio/wikiviews
you just call it like `python wikiviews 2 2015` and it will download all the files for February 2015, and join them in a single file.